# ng-class not taking both classes

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

i have an ng-class like this

```
ng-class="{'alert alert-success': response.submitSuccess , 'alert alert-danger': !response.submitSuccess  }"
```

the problem is , suppose "response.submitSuccess" returns true , only alert-success class is added and not the alert class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't it make more sense to make the `alert` class permanent then? (rhetorical question)

You can do it like this:

```
class="alert" ng-class="{'alert-success': response.submitSuccess , 'alert-danger': !response.submitSuccess}"
```

And this is the reason for the behaviour (it removes the `alert` class that was previously set by the `!response.submitSuccess` condition because it was falsy before):

> When the expression changes, the previously added classes are removed and only then the new classes are added.

From: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: You are right , the second condition was removing it. I fixed it by making alert permanent. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I mean, even if it was working like that (and it probably should, maybe this is an angular bug), there was really no reason to keep the common class conditional since it's always present.

Comment: So does this mean i can never add 2 different classes based on 2 different conditions ?(as the previuosly set classes are removed as expression changes)

Comment: I'll have to test it out, but I think this affect only when the *same* class is being set on two directly opposing conditions... I assume it would've worked if you had classes A and B for the condition 1, and classes C and D for the condition 2 (and not A and B; and A and C), if that makes sense.